# Configuring hive in local mode

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

I am trying to set up hive-0.9.0 in local mode configuration. In /conf, I have created hive-site.xml and specified the property for warehouse folder.
But I think hive is not using my defined location as it is not creating the 'warehouse' folder in that location.

Also, is it necessary to have hadoop cluster running in local mode hive configuration as it throws error when I issue any DDL commands without starting hadoop cluster.

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.net.ConnectException Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
```

The contents of hive-site.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

<property>

<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>

<value>/home/hadoopuser/hive/warehouse</value>

<description>

Local or HDFS directory where Hive keeps table contents.

</description>

</property>

<property>

<name>hive.metastore.local</name>

<value>true</value>

<description>

Use false if a production metastore server is used.

</description>

</property>

<property>

<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>

<value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/hadoopuser/hive/metastore_db;create=true</value>

<description>

The JDBC connection URL.

</description>

</property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive queries internally runs mapreduce. So hadoop has to be up while you are trying to query Hive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Any idea why hive is not using my local warehouse folder and storing the databases/tables on hdfs cluster?

Comment: What I found was : " hive-default.xml.template contains the default values for various configuration variables that come with prepackaged in a Hive distribution. In order to override any of the values, create hive-site.xml instead and set the value in that file. Please note that this file is not used by Hive at all (as of Hive 0.9.0) and so it might be out of date or out of sync with the actual values. The canonical list of configuration options is now only managed in the HiveConf java class. "

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/adminmanual-configuration.html (Reference for my comment)